# Creating custom checkbox without after element

Tags: css

I am trying to make custom checkbox using pure CSS, without required label element,  i know there is a lot of answer but i didn't manage to make it as i need to. 
Only problem is i have when checkbox is checked, there i do not know how to add checked sign, here is what I have for now

```css
.checkbox-custom {
  &:after {
    line-height: 1.5em;
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    width: 18px;
    height: 18px;
    margin-top: -4px;
    margin-left: -4px;
    border: 1px solid grey;
    border-radius: 0;
    background-color: white;
  }
  &:checked:after {
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    color: grey;
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-custom">
```

Comment: You can use both :before and :after. Check out this one I made a few years ago https://codepen.io/phiter/pen/KvVPBr

Comment: I need to be stylled like chekcbox, only problem as i sais i have with the checked styling

Comment: If you read trough my CSS you'll understand what you can work with. You can use the before for the base and after for the checked element.

Comment: Note that the `<input>` tag does not use or need a closing slash and never has in HTML.

Comment: if you only need a checkmark you could use `&:checked:after {
      content:'\2713'; }`  or search any other entity

Comment: Txanks @Rob you are the greatest

Comment: Check this one https://jsfiddle.net/aspyn9rg/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if your are looking to add a checkmark to the after, use `content`with a html entity (css encoded)

```css
.checkbox-custom::after {
  line-height: 1.5em;
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  margin-top: -4px;
  margin-left: -4px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  border-radius: 0;
  background-color: white;
}

.checkbox-custom:checked::after {
  content:'\2713';
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 1em;
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  color: grey;
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-custom">
```

Comment: Txanks it is closed, but not check in the middle :(

Comment: i know, you could use `::before`with content to position it better maybe

Comment: O mete, but i dont know how to do that :(

Comment: just add `text-align: center;` to the after, i edited my answer

Comment: it is not work with firefox